# Override a Magento framework file

Tags: magento2

I want to change the default max size of images defined in

`vendor/magento/framework/File/Uploader.php`

In that file the size defined 1920x1200
I want to reduce that and want to override it.
where I can put this file in my custom theme or module.

Comment: You can Put In Custom Module by defining in di.xml

Comment: can you please give little more hint. also will it work globally or for that module only?

Comment: It Will work with in the module as per my knowledge

Comment: Its more better to override the template, because de maxWidth and the maxHeight are used as constante.

Comment: did you override it,whether it works

Answer (score -2):

Follow below steps:

1) create a module inside app/code/Vendor/Module.

2) Inside etc/di.xml file;

```
<preference for="Magento\Framework\File\Uploader" type="Vendor\Module\File\Uploader" />
```

3) Now just create one folder under Module, File and create Uploader.php file under

app/code/Vendor/Module/File Uploader.php file:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\File;

use Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DriverInterface;


class Uploader extends \Magento\Framework\File\Uploader
{
/**
 * Uploaded file handle (copy of $_FILES[] element)
 *
 * @var array
 * @access protected
 */
protected $_file;

/**
 * Uploaded file mime type
 *
 * @var string
 * @access protected
 */
protected $_fileMimeType;

/**
 * Upload type. Used to right handle $_FILES array.
 *
 * @var \Magento\Framework\File\Uploader::SINGLE_STYLE|\Magento\Framework\File\Uploader::MULTIPLE_STYLE
 * @access protected
 */
protected $_uploadType;

/**
 * The name of uploaded file. By default it is original file name, but when
 * we will change file name, this variable will be changed too.
 *
 * @var string
 * @access protected
 */
protected $_uploadedFileName;

/**
 * The name of destination directory
 *
 * @var string
 * @access protected
 */
protected $_uploadedFileDir;

/**
 * If this variable is set to TRUE, our library will be able to automatically create
 * non-existent directories.
 *
 * @var bool
 * @access protected
 */
protected $_allowCreateFolders = true;

/**
 * If this variable is set to TRUE, uploaded file name will be changed if some file with the same
 * name already exists in the destination directory (if enabled).
 *
 * @var bool
 * @access protected
 */
protected $_allowRenameFiles = false;

/**
 * If this variable is set to TRUE, files dispertion will be supported.
 *
 * @var bool
 * @access protected
 */
protected $_enableFilesDispersion = false;

/**
 * This variable is used both with $_enableFilesDispersion == true
 * It helps to avoid problems after migrating from case-insensitive file system to case-insensitive
 * (e.g. NTFS->ext or ext->NTFS)
 *
 * @var bool
 * @access protected
 */
protected $_caseInsensitiveFilenames = true;

/**
 * @var string
 * @access protected
 */
protected $_dispretionPath = null;

/**
 * @var bool
 */
protected $_fileExists = false;

/**
 * @var null|string[]
 */
protected $_allowedExtensions = null;

/**
 * Validate callbacks storage
 *
 * @var array
 * @access protected
 */
protected $_validateCallbacks = [];

/**#@+
 * File upload type (multiple or single)
 */
const SINGLE_STYLE = 0;

const MULTIPLE_STYLE = 1;

/**#@-*/

/**
 * Temp file name empty code
 */
const TMP_NAME_EMPTY = 666;

/**
 * Max Image Width resolution in pixels. For image resizing on client side
 */
const MAX_IMAGE_WIDTH = 1920;

/**
 * Max Image Height resolution in pixels. For image resizing on client side
 */
const MAX_IMAGE_HEIGHT = 1200;
}
```

Hope this helps you !!

Comment: I want this to be overridden globally. will it work that way? like uploading images for the product.

Comment: Yes, It will. You can also increase your server upload limit.

Comment: Hi Saurabh - No luck. I created the file Uploader.php in folder File. The module is registered and installed correctly. I also ran `setup:di:compile` but still the images are getting resized at 1920x1200. whereas I have modified the `Uploader.php` to `1000x800`

Comment: Its more better to override the template, because de maxWidth and the maxHeight are used as constante. @Joshi

Answer (score -2):

While Overrding the Default Files By Mentioning in the di.xml of Custom module.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Framework\File\Uploader" type="Vendor\Module\File\Uploader" />
</config>
```

Comment: it is not working